# laravel MySQL query optimization

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following sql queries in my application.

```
$defaultGoal = DB::table("goals")
-> where("activitiesID", "=", $this->activityID)
-> where("usersID", "=", $userID)
-> pluck("goal");

$defaultGoalPoints = DB::table("goals")
-> where("activitiesID", "=", $this->activityID)
-> where("usersID", "=", $userID)
-> pluck("goalpoints");

$defaultPoints = DB::table("goals")
-> where("activitiesID", "=", $this->activityID)
-> where("usersID", "=", $userID)
-> pluck("points");
```

Each query returns an array. Is there a way to do combine all of these queries into one, that will return the same arrays for `$defaultPoints`, `$defaultGoalPoints`, and `$defaultGoal`.

Comment: If the goal is to reduce the number of queries you're writing, what about simply using ->get() to retrieve the entire entries and then using php to pull the data you want into arrays? (Laravel may have a shorter way to do this though, and I'll let someone else speak up if they know of it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select` to get only what you need:

```
$defaults = DB::table("goals")
->select('goal', 'goalpoints', 'points')
->where("activitiesID", "=", $this->activityID)
->where("usersID", "=", $userID)
->get();
```

Hope it helps...